# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found, when i close the scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

so i have 3 different classes and each has a scanner. in the main method i loop through these classes and give my input several times for each of them. the problem is when i close the scanner (scanner.close();) i can only iterate one time, the first class which executes and then i get this error: **Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found**. when i don't close the scanner everything is fine but i don't want to have memory leaks. if posting the code would help you understand my problem better please let me know

the code

'''
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Employee new_guard[] = new Guard[5];
    Employee new_it[] = new ITPersonal[5];
    Employee new_manager[] = new Management[5];
    int count_guard = 0, count_it = 0, count_manager = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0){
            new_guard[count_guard] = new Guard();
            new_guard[count_guard].input_variables();
            count_guard++;
            System.out.println();
        }else if(i % 2 == 0){
            new_it[count_it] = new ITPersonal();
            new_it[count_it].input_variables();
            count_it++;
            System.out.println();
        }else{
            new_manager[count_manager] = new Management();
            new_manager[count_manager].input_variables();
            count_manager++;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    int k = 0, j = 0, l = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0){
            System.out.println(new_manager[k].toString());
                k++;
            }else if(i % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println(new_it[j].toString());
                j++;
            }else{
                System.out.println(new_guard[l].toString());
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

abstract public class Employee{

```
public Employee(){}

String name, surname, rang;
int salary = 0, daysoff = 20;

public Employee(String name, String surname, String rank, int salary, int daysoff){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.daysoff= daysoff;
}
```

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guard extends Employee{

```
String rang = "Guard";
int night_shifts, early_shifts, late_shifts;   

public Guard(){}

public void input_variables(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("First name: ");
    this.name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Last name: ");
    this.surname = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Night shifts (per month): ");
    this.night_shifts = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Late shifts (per month): ");
    this.late_shifts = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Night shifts (per month): ");
    this.early_shifts = scan.nextInt();
    // scan.close();
    System.out.printf("Added %s, %s to company!", this.surname, this.name);
}

public int getSalary(){
    return salary = 160 * night_shifts + 100 * (early_shifts + late_shifts);
}

public int getDaysOff(){
    return daysoff += 0.25 * (early_shifts + late_shifts + night_shifts);
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s, %s (%s): Shifts %d/%d/%d; Monthly salary = %d EURO; %d offdays.", 
    surname, name, rank, early_shifts, late_shifts, night_shifts, getSalary(), getDaysOff());
}
```

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ITPersonal extends Employee{

```
String rang;
int year_joined, weekhours, daysoff = 22;
int current_year = 2021, bonusdays = 0;

public ITPersonal(){}

public void input_variables(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("First name: ");
    this.name = scan.nextLine();        
    System.out.println("Last name: ");
    this.surname = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter rank (\"Junior Developer" + " or " + "Senior Developer\"): \"");
    this.rank = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Year joined: ");
    this.year_joined = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Week hours: ");
    this.weekhours = scan.nextInt();
    // scan.close();
    System.out.printf("Added %s, %s to company!", this.surname, this.name);
}

public int getDaysOff(){

    if(current_year - year_joined >= 3){
        if((current_year - year_joined) % 3 == 0){
            if((current_year - year_joined) / 3 >= 5){
                bonusDays = 5;
            }else
                bonusDays = (current_year - year_joined) / 3;
        }else{
            if((current_year - year_joined) / 3 >= 5){
                bonusDays = 5;
            }else
                bonusDays = (current_year - year_joined) % 3;
        }
    } 

    if(this.rang == "Senior Developer"){
        daysoff += bonusTage;
    }else
        daysoff = 22;

    return daysoff;
}

public int getSalary(){
    if(rang == "Junior Developer"){
        salary = 25 * weekhours;
    }else{
        salary = (32 * weekhours) + current_year - year_joined;
    }

    return salary;
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s, %s (%s): Weekhours = %d; Monthly salary = %d EURO; %d offdays.", 
    this.surname, this.name, this.rank, this.weekhours, getSalary(), getDaysOff());
}
```

}

'''

Comment: **ALWAYS** post your code. When you describe something, that's your personal interpretation of what's happening, which may or may not reflect reality. If you post your code, you eliminate all the guessing and conjecture that only lengthens the time before someone can give the correct answer. Read the Stack Overflow help file section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions which will receive good answers.

Comment: If your taking input from the terminal you should never close the Scanner. This also closes the console inputStream. Otherwise, post an [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`Scanner` is not the issue.
When initializing a Scanner you're probably doing

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

The problem is when calling `scanner.close()`, `scanner` is closing `System.in`, which is a singleton for the process (The stream that reads from the console).
Wrapping a singleton (`System.in`) with regular classes is not a solution to hide its existence.

To overcome this issue you need to initialize `Scanner` only once and close it at the end of the program (only once). Then give your classes the reference to Scanner through `Dependency Injection`.

A pretty implementation of this is using `try with resource`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            // the rest of your program
        } // scanner is automatically closed after the try block.
    }
}
```